# How do I dynamically allocate my array, reallocate to twice, etc.?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am supposed to create a member function with the following behavior:
void grow()

- If the array is empty (i.e. num_elements_ is 0 and data_ is a nullptr) set the num_elements_ to 2 and dynamically allocate data_ to be of size 2.
- Otherwise, reallocate data_ with twice as many num_elements_ and the correct keys stored internally, taking care to manage the dynamically allocated memory correctly

I am not sure how to dynamically allocate data_ to be size 2 and also the second bullet all together. This has me very confused.

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::boolalpha; using std::ostream;
#include<initializer_list>
using std::initializer_list;
#include <algorithm> 
using std::max; using std::copy; using std::swap; 
#include <utility> 
using std::make_pair; using std::pair; 
#include <stdexcept> 
using std::runtime_error; 
#include<vector>
using std::vector;

const static size_t element_array_size = 5;

template<typename K, typename V>
struct Element{
public:
  K key_;
  V values_[element_array_size];//capacity of values
  size_t count_ = 0; //number of values filling values_
  Element()=default;
  Element(K, initializer_list<V>);
  bool operator==(const Element&)const;
  bool operator<(const K&) const; 

  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Element& ele){//output element ele
        os<<ele.key_<<":";//display key
        std::copy(ele.values_,(ele.values_+ele.count_-1),std::ostream_iterator<V>(os,","));//display values
        os<<ele.values_[ele.count_-1];
return os;
};//of friend function
};
//count_ and num_keys_ should never be greater than the size or num_elements_
//Code for Element functions goes here

template<typename K, typename V> 
class MVM{
public:
  Element<K, V> *data_ = nullptr;
  size_t num_keys_ = 0; 
  size_t num_elements_ = 0; //capacity
  Element<K, V> *find_key(K);
  size_t find_value(V, K*&);
  void grow(); 

public:
  MVM()=default;
  MVM(initializer_list<Element<K,V>>);
  MVM(const MVM&); 
  ~MVM() {delete[] data_;} 
  size_t size();
  bool add(K,V);  
  bool remove_key(K);
  size_t remove_value(V, K*&);
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& oss, const MVM& mv){
    //Code for the ostream operator goes here
    std::copy(mv.data_,(mv.data_+mv.num_keys_-1),std::ostream_iterator<Element<K,V>>(oss," "));//copy elements with spaces in between to ostream oss
    oss<<mv.data_[mv.num_keys_-1];
return oss;
  }//of friend function
};

...
```

Comment: It is hard for us to tell you what you have gotten wrong when there are no signs of you having done anything. By the way, someone's going to ask why you include `vector` and then write your own `vector` instead of using `vector`, so it might as well be me.

Comment: Nothing is wrong yet. I am not sure where to even begin the grow() function. We aren't supposed to use vectors either. The include can for now be ignored.

Comment: in that case, begin with `new T[]` and `delete[]`.  I recommend starting with something simple, like `int` and once you have a good grip on that, start mucking around with the templates.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a vector, you can create a larger one using:

```
vector<string> Wibble;
Wibble.resize(10);
...
// or:
...
Wibble.push_back("hello");
Wibble.push_back("world");
```

Or, if you are using C you can go the malloc route, as long as you remember to free afterwards:

```
char *Data=(char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
...
Data=(char *)realloc(Data,20*sizeof(char));
...
free(Data);
```

What you can't do is chuck some statically sized stuff on a stack and then change your mind:

```
char Data[10];
```

Will always be size 10, any attempt to change the size will cause you problems.

Comment: No need for the casts on the `malloc` return in C. `void*` is much more malleable in C than C++. Why bring this up on a question tagged C++?

Comment: Fair comment, it's just that some people use C with classes. And the title does mention reallocation, so I added it anyway.